# Native .NET NuGet package causes "There may have been missing assembly" warning by .NET compiler

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, win-universal-app, nuget-package

I have a Universal Windows Application Runtime Component project, which depends on 
`Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client` NuGet package.This generic runtime component is then used by another project written in Visual C++ which is also of Universal Windows Application project type. Now the C# project compiles fine by it self and so does the C++ project, but when building the solution which references the C# project from C++ project where the C# project is using the NuGet package, the compiler gives the following warning: `'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in type 'AzureConnection.Connection'. There may have been a missing assembly.` There definitely is missing assembly as the program crashes when it's trying to call any code that comes from the NuGet package.

This basically means that the NuGet packages are not properly being used in compile time, as `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient` type comes from the NuGet package. I can see from the Visual Studio NuGet package manager that the package `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client` is properly installed in my C# Runtime Component project. The same problem is present when trying to make release build for any platform.

Why doesn't the build find the NuGet binaries and how could I fix this?

Comment: This works rather poorly.  I lost an hour of my life trying to whack MSBuild over the head but only managed to get rid of the warning, it still can't activate at runtime.  The package clearly was never tested in this specific scenario, it works fine when you use it from a C# app.  Click the "Contact Owners" link in the Nuget package to get help from the authors.

Comment: @HansPassant So are you saying there is currently no other solution for this problem but to write the entire app in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no way to use this NuGet package in Generic Runtime Component project as the package is not properly compiled into the component. I had to solve the problem by migrating my code into a single C# application where the NuGet package compiles and works fine.